# Multiprocessing/multithreading for database query in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, denodo

I have millions of records in database and I want to read it through Python and store it in pandas data frame .
The problem is the select query processing time is very high.
To reduce the query processing time I try to perform multi threading on it
I created 3 threads and make the query on basis of each thread like

```
Select * from ( select *,rownum over (order by col1) rn from table) where rn%3=0 


Select * from ( select *,rownum over (order by col1) rn from table) where rn%3=1


Select * from ( select *,rownum over (order by col1) rn from table) where rn%3=2
```

Then I run the each query with threading in Python by threading package.

But it also not reducing the time much

Is there any other approach I can take to reduce the query  reading time.
Note- I have used both jdbc and odbc connection

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658348/reading-large-tables-into-pandas-is-there-a-intermediate-step

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I am doing query to a virtualization tool named DENODO. One strange thing I noticed that when I am running the simple query select * from table, it takes same time what my threading query (mention in actual problem) is taking . I am still not sure why it is happening. I have created diffrent jdbc connection for each thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link helped me
[Multiprocessing with JDBC connection and pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402203/multiprocessing-with-jdbc-connection-and-pooling)
I can get around 25%  gain on my local.machine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multi-threading only if the underlying database engine supports it. You should check for that. For your question, I think the attached link will help you:
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309714/how-do-i-multithread-sql-queries-in-python-such-that-i-obtain-the-results-of-all)
If the answer helps you then help the community by selecting it as the best answer.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I am doing query to a virtualization tool named DENODO. One strange thing I noticed that when I am running the simple query select * from table, it takes same time what my threading query (mention in actual problem) is taking . I am still not sure why it is happening. I have created diffrent jdbc connection for each thread.